# How to run a External JavaScript String in Angular Context?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a usecase where a user will be allowed to enter some js code (vanilla JS) in a Text area and upon clicking of a button that JS will be executed  in Angular.

I am trying to use DOM Sanitizer to make sure that the js is not a security risk  while running in Angular Context but the JS just dosent seem to work.

Here is what i have tried.

**TS file**

```
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("sss");
    let script = 'alert("ddd")';
    this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(script);
  }
```

I even tried with innerHtml and used it in a div but it dosen't work any idea how we can get it to work , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use **eval()**

```
eval("alert('Hello World!');");
```

Greetings, Javier Guajardo.

Comment: the problem with eval is it is not safe user can still embeed Xss scripts